# query multiple sharepoint task list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Please I need to query multiple SharePoint default task list using SharePoint Rest API. With the code below I can only query one list,

```
https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Tasklist')/items?$top=1
```

how do I query multiple task list from the same site collection.

Comment: Refer this link - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128725/query-1-list-from-multiple-sites-using-a-single-rest-call